# What is this bump/scab on my 10 year old cat's nose?

Tags: cats

This bump started about 1 month ago, thought it was just a graze or small cut, then it increased in size and developed this crusty scabby surface. As you can see, his fur is now growing over it too. Oskar is not distressed by it at all, and there is no pain, even when I touch it.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Pets! We sometimes get very similar questions, so instead of repeating the answers I linked you to the existing ones. If you feel like those linked questions don't answer your question, please add a comment describing how yours differs.